# Why kdenlive is becoming grey when doing anything at all?

Tags: video, screen, kdenlive

Ubuntu 15.4, I've opened kdenlive for the first time since few months to edit view videos for youtube, suddenly I'm trying to just preview a video recorded with a camera and everything is turning grey for about 5 minutes, then I can work for few seconds until I hit play, click anywhere or do anything and app is becoming grey again... It was working fine until now... thinking if there is a point of any updates, they are only making everything go wrong...

My Laptop:
Core i5
8GB RAM
2GB Radeon

Answer (score 0):

You know the "does not respond" from Windows when all hope is lost? Linux also has this and a window becoming gray is the stage before it: It probably will come back after some time, but maybe the "'Kill or wait?' message" will pop up.

Comment: @Chris Koval Did this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking, just can't solve the problem I'm having, I've tried to reinstall it, changed kdenlive versions few times, could using MTS video formats be the reason for that?

Comment: Converted videos to mpg and avi, works fine now.. thanks anyway:)

Comment: @ChrisKoval If it answered your question, please press mark the answer as accepted.